# How do I customize the home screen of Ubuntu and Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

I need to install Xubuntu or Ubuntu for a small company and one of the requirements is that the home screen is the logo of this company, I have tried several applications without success I would like to know where these images stay in the system and thus replace them .

Comment: are you customizing with Cubic? Or you just want to replace the entire background images?

Comment: Hi, I just want to replace the images

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04

For those who are looking for extending the current list of wallpapers with your own (example:music-wallpaper-3840x2160.jpg):

Step-1: Copy the desired wallpaper in target folder /usr/share/backgrounds/

Step-2: Edit file:/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/bionic-wallpapers.xml

Step-3: Create an entry as shown below:

```
 <wallpaper>
 <name>Music-1</name>
 <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/music-wallpaper-3840x2160.jpg</filename>
 <options>zoom</options>
 <pcolor>#000000</pcolor>
 <scolor>#000000</scolor>
 <shade_type>solid</shade_type>
 </wallpaper>
```